# How to combine two tables into one table using the data from one table as the columns?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, person(id, phonetype, phonenumber), phonetype(id, txtDisplay). For example

Phonetye

```
Id  txtDisplay
1   Home Phone
2   Work Phone
3   Mobile Phone
```

Person

```
Id  phonetype   phonenumber
0001    1       6310001111
0001    2       6310001112
0002    3       5160002113
0003    2       7180003112
```

The result table should be

```
Id  home_phone  work_phone  mobile_phone
0001    6310001111  6310001112
0002                    5160002113
0003            7180003112
```

How do I write a query for this?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, assume anyone who tags their question `sql` is talking about Microsoft SQL Server.  Microsoft likes to pretend that general-purpose words always mean *their* product.  Cf. Microsoft Word, Microsoft Windows, Microsoft Money.  :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin - Interestingly , there is a lot of users fall in this. [here is a sample one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685394/sql-dynamic-date-comparison#comment18788200_13685394)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work only if you know already all the phone types:

```
SELECT
  id,
  max(case when phonetype=1 then phonenumber end) as home_phone,
  max(case when phonetype=2 then phonenumber end) as work_phone,
  max(case when phonetype=3 then phonenumber end) as mobile_phone
FROM Person
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, the column names must be known at the time the query is parsed.  You can't write a query that automatically expands the number of columns depending on what data it finds.

You can, however do it in two queries:

1. First, fetch all the distinct phone number types from your Phonetype table.
2. Second, write code to add as many columns as you have distinct phone number types.

Microsoft SQL Server supports a [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operation that helps for these types of queries a little bit, but you must still know all the distinct values for which you want columns.  So my two-step process above applies to Microsoft as well as any other implementation of SQL.