# sql dynamic date comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my database I have two columns one (Obtained) sets a date (`2012-08-03 14:18:39`) when an entry is first made. The second column (Processed) sets a date when that entry is processed. I would like a query that looks for entries in the database where over two days’ time have passed between obtaining and processing of the entries.

Is this possible?

Comment: is it Sql or Mysql? You have both tags..

Comment: @Robuust I think there is no problem with tagging it with both tags in the same time. It is still SQL.

Comment: @robuust - SQL isn't a DBMS, it's a language, so it isn't a conflict to tag with both SQL and MySQL.

Comment: Check the tooltip please @MahmoudGamal and DMac. SQL does not refer to MySQL

Comment: @Robuust SQL doesn't refer to a specific RDBMS. Thats why any question tagged with SQL hase to be tagged with a RDBMS like MySQL, SQL Server, Orable, etc... May be if he is asking about some thing in the administration of the MySQL not the SQL language it self may be he can ignore the SQL tag.

Answer (score 2):

In contrast with the answers that suggest [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), which only uses the `DATE` part of your timestamps, [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) enables you to return records where at least two full days (i.e. 48 hours) have elapsed:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, Obtained, Processed) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following query

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DATEADD(Obtained, INTERVAL 2 DAY) <= Processed
```